# Paypal Java SDK - how do I configure the .properties File?

Tags: java, paypal

I am trying to connect to my Paypal Business Account via the Java Paypal SDK to automatically send invoices. I configured the .properties File like this:

```
http.ConnectionTimeOut=5000
http.Retry=1
http.ReadTimeOut=30000
http.MaxConnection=100

# HTTP Proxy configuration
# If you are using proxy set http.UseProxy to true and replace the following         
values with your proxy parameters
http.ProxyPort=8080
http.ProxyHost=127.0.0.1
http.UseProxy=false
http.ProxyUserName=null
http.ProxyPassword=null

#Set this property to true if you are using the PayPal SDK within a Google   
App Engine java app
http.GoogleAppEngine = false

# Service Configuration
service.EndPoint=https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
# Live EndPoint
# service.EndPoint=https://api.paypal.com

# Credentials
clientId=ID (of SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS)
clientSecret=SECRET (of SANDBOX API CREDENTIALS)

# Webhook Validation
#webhook.trustCert=DigiCertSHA2ExtendedValidationServerCA.crt
```

When it connects I get "Error Message : No API accounts have been configured in application properties". What is wrong with my .properties File?

Comment: I don't see any API credentials configured?  https://github.com/paypal/sdk-core-java/wiki/SDK-Configuration-Parameters

Comment: clientId and clientSecret are replaced by ID and SECRET. Or do I need the acctX credentials too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PayPal Java SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/) to create invoices. You can read some samples on how to create an invoice using this using these links:

- https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/wiki/Making-First-Call
- https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sample/src/main/java/com/paypal/api/sample/InvoiceSample.java